# Merging adjacent date intervals into a single row

Tags: oracle, gaps-and-islands

**Here is the scenario:**
If the employee transaction is continuous display as-is. if the employee got any gap display as a new row.

**Below is the sample table**

```
Emid    Fromdate    Todate
-----   --------    ------
A   1/1/2012    12/31/2012
A   12/31/2012  12/31/2013
A   12/31/2013  12/31/2014
A   2/2/2015    12/31/2099
```

**Expected output:**

```
emid    Fromdate    Todate
======  ========    ========
A   1/1/2012    12/31/2014
A   2/2/2015    12/31/2099
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

[edit] fixed a bug .. comment on line fixed [/edit]

```
with w_data as (
        select 'A' emid, to_date('01/01/2012','mm/dd/yyyy') fromdate, to_date('12/31/2012','mm/dd/yyyy') todate from dual union all
        select 'A' emid, to_date('12/31/2012','mm/dd/yyyy') fromdate, to_date('12/31/2013','mm/dd/yyyy') todate from dual union all
        select 'A' emid, to_date('12/31/2013','mm/dd/yyyy') fromdate, to_date('12/31/2014','mm/dd/yyyy') todate from dual union all
        select 'A' emid, to_date('02/02/2015','mm/dd/yyyy') fromdate, to_date('12/31/2099','mm/dd/yyyy') todate from dual union all
        select 'B' emid, to_date('05/12/2013','mm/dd/yyyy') fromdate, to_date('11/23/2013','mm/dd/yyyy') todate from dual union all
        select 'B' emid, to_date('11/23/2013','mm/dd/yyyy') fromdate, to_date('12/30/2013','mm/dd/yyyy') todate from dual union all
        select 'B' emid, to_date('01/10/2014','mm/dd/yyyy') fromdate, to_date('03/22/2014','mm/dd/yyyy') todate from dual union all
        select 'B' emid, to_date('04/03/2014','mm/dd/yyyy') fromdate, to_date('12/31/2099','mm/dd/yyyy') todate from dual union all
        select 'C' emid, to_date('05/12/2013','mm/dd/yyyy') fromdate, to_date('11/23/2013','mm/dd/yyyy') todate from dual union all
        select 'C' emid, to_date('11/23/2013','mm/dd/yyyy') fromdate, to_date('01/10/2014','mm/dd/yyyy') todate from dual union all
        select 'C' emid, to_date('01/10/2014','mm/dd/yyyy') fromdate, to_date('04/03/2014','mm/dd/yyyy') todate from dual union all
        select 'C' emid, to_date('04/03/2014','mm/dd/yyyy') fromdate, to_date('12/31/2099','mm/dd/yyyy') todate from dual  
        ),
  w_sub as (
     select emid, fromdate, todate,
              sum(grp) over (partition by emid order by fromdate) grp_id  -- added partition by .. forgot to group it by employee
       from (
              select emid, fromdate, todate,
                     case when fromdate = lag(todate) over (partition by emid order by fromdate) 
                       then 0 else 1 end  grp
                from w_data
             )
        )
select emid, min(fromdate) fromdate, max(todate) todate
  from w_sub
 group by emid, grp_id
 order by emid, grp_id, fromdate
/

E FROMDATE    TODATE
- ----------- -----------
A 01-jan-2012 31-dec-2014
A 02-feb-2015 31-dec-2099
B 12-may-2013 30-dec-2013
B 10-jan-2014 22-mar-2014
B 03-apr-2014 31-dec-2099
C 12-may-2013 31-dec-2099

6 rows selected.
```

Comment: I will accept this will work for this sample. But if we have a lot of employees then how it will work.

Comment: it'll work just fine .. (once I fix the bug I have in there :)  I'll fix my original post .. give me a second :)

Comment: @ ditto. So manually we have to give the employees in with clause function right.

Comment: No, the with clause w_data is just to mimick your source table. you can remove that and change the reference to w_data in the main query to your driving table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @T TABLE(ID INT,FromDate DATETIME, ToDate DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @T(ID,FromDate,ToDate)
SELECT 1,'20090801','20090803' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'20090802','20090809' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'20090805','20090806' UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'20090812','20090813' UNION ALL
SELECT 5,'20090811','20090812' UNION ALL
SELECT 6,'20090802','20090802'


SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s1.FromDate) AS ID,
       s1.FromDate, 
       MIN(t1.ToDate) AS ToDate 
FROM @T s1 
INNER JOIN @T t1 ON s1.FromDate <= t1.ToDate 
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @T t2 
                 WHERE t1.ToDate >= t2.FromDate
                   AND t1.ToDate < t2.ToDate) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @T s2 
                 WHERE s1.FromDate > s2.FromDate
                   AND s1.FromDate <= s2.ToDate) 
GROUP BY s1.FromDate 
ORDER BY s1.FromDate
```